# Вывести слайдер owl carousel из custom field Wordpress без плагина

Tags: php, wordpress

Нужно вывести слайдер из поля `the_sub_field('owl_carousel')` без плагина, средствами Wordpress.

Использую этот код:

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
        <?php while( have_rows('project_sections') ): the_row(); ?>
            <section class="<?php if ($i % 2 == 0) : ?>bg-gray<?php else: ?>bg-white<?php endif; ?>">
                <div class="container">
                    <h2 class="page-head_sub-title"><?php the_sub_field('project_sections_title'); ?></h2>
                    <?php the_sub_field('project_sections_description'); ?>
                    <?php //var_dump(get_sub_field('owl_carousel')); ?>
                </div>
                <?php
                $args = array(
                    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                    'post_type' => 'attachment',
                    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'numberposts' => 1, // number of images (slides)
                    'post_mime_type' => 'image'
                );
                if ( $images = get_children( $args ) ) {
                    // if there are no images in post, don't display anything
                    echo '<div class="owl-carousel-wrap project-gallery ">
                                <div id="projectGalleryProject" class="owl-carousel owl-loaded owl-drag">
                                <a href="#projectPhotosProject" data-slide-to="0">
                                ';
                    foreach( $images as $image ) {
                        echo '<div class="item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#projectGalleryProjectModal"><div class="project-gallery_item">' . wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, 'project_slider' ) . '</div></div>';
                    }
                    echo '</a></div></div>';
                }
                ?>
                <div class="js-control-project-gallery-project">
                    <div class="carousel-control-prev" aria-hidden="true"><span class="icon-arrow"></span></div>
                    <div class="carousel-control-next" aria-hidden="true"><span class="icon-arrow"></span></div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <?php $i++; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Выводятся все загруженные изображения, кроме добавленных непосредственно в поле слайдера. Нужно как-то обратиться к полю `'owl_carousel'`, и наверное, нужно сделать проверку на существование значений в поле для каждой секции `if exist`. Т.е. если изображения загружены в слайдер, то показать слайдер.

Как изменить существующий код для корректного отображения слайдера?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Надо было обратиться к полю `get_sub_field('owl_carousel')`

```
<?php if($images = get_sub_field('owl_carousel')){
                    echo '<div class="owl-carousel-wrap project-gallery"><div id="projectGalleryProject" class="owl-carousel owl-loaded owl-drag">';
                    for($i=0; $i<count($images); $i++){
                        echo "<a href='#projectPhotosProject' data-slide-to='{$i}'><div class='project-gallery_item'><img src='{$images[$i]['url']}' alt='{$images[$i]['alt']}'></div></a>";
                    }
                    echo "</a></div>

                </div>";
                }
                ?>
```